# Android iniciar apenas meu aplicativo

Tags: android

Não sei se isto seria um problema de programação, eu creio que sim...
Eu estou com um projeto a qual o aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo vai ser instalado em aparelhos de uma marca X, este aplicativo DEVE ser o único app utilizável, ou seja, o usuário não pode ter poder de fechar o app, "minimizar", iniciar outros apps ou até usar a barra de status do android, resumindo, um aparelho que funcione apenas um app. Tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resumidamente ... **Não**

O Android é um sistema operacional e o seu aplicativo é apenas um processo que roda nele, você simplesmente não pode travar todos os recursos exclusivamente para o seu app. Mesmo que você tente fazer isso, uma hora ou outra, o Android vai matar o seu processo.

No final das contas, o que você está querendo fazer é um [sistema embarcado](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_embarcado), ou seja, criando uma aplicação que roda de maneira exclusiva em um hardware específico.

Comment: Um complemento para sua resposta, e o que responderia 100% a minha: Android Things! https://developer.android.com/things/index.html